# Ruby, how do I split a simple_form with multiple fields across multiple screens so it's 1 field per screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, simple-form-for

Could not find the answer for how to split a simple_form across multiple screens so that it's one form per screen, then you confirm.

I have a big form with:

- First field requires you to select an option from a dropdown
- Second field is an input
- Third field is a date picker
- Fourth field is free text
- Submit button

I'd like this to be split across four screens so it's less overwhelming for the user, and it just looks nicer. What would be the best way to do that?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You can either have a 'next' button that saves the data locally, but doesn't send it to the server until you've done all the pages.

Comment: Other option is to have a controller action for each page, and save the progress through the form in your server instead of locally

Comment: What do you even mean by "screens"? Do you want to split it into separate requests (steps)? Do you want to use JS and create something like a carousel which displays one step at a time? Also any question containing "Whats best way to do that?" is problematic as the answer is almost always based on opinion. Here the best answer depends on the UX requirements and how much time you're willing to spend on the feature.

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a similar requirement and this seems to work for us.

```
in controller..

def new
  ...
end

def create
  record.step = 1
  # create record
  ...
  render step_2
end

def step_2
  ...
end

# POST /controller/:id/update_step_2
def update_step_2
  record.step = 2
  # update object
  ...
end
```

`step` is a attr_acessor in model. This will be used in validation conditions.